Variable in root not populated from module
My folder structure is as below:

data.tf
main.tf
variables.tf
version.tf (declares standard_tags variable without default)
state_initiatlization

data.tf
main.tf
variables.tf



the main.tf inside 'state_initialization' folder is as below:
module "state_initialisation_tagging" {
 source = "../"
 standard_tags = data.terraform_remote_state.param_store_tags.outputs.standard_tags
 .. others...
}

and the data.tf in that same folder has data resource defined with s3 as backend.
But when i do terraform plan at the module level i get the below error msg. What am i missing? I am assuming I dont need to output the variable as the standard_tags = data.remote_state.xxx in the module main.tf is taking care of that.
The root module input variable "standard_tags" is not set, and has no default value. Use a -var or
│ -var-file command line argument to provide a value for this variable.


Not sure if I am missing something here, but shouldn't the path to the module be source = "./state_initiatlization"?

@MarkoE, the main.tf is already in that folder and source is pointing to the root location.

Uhm, so why call it as a module then? Are you trying to run plan and apply from that same directory?

I am running plan from 'state_initialization' folder. The folder structure is pre-defined as part of corporate tempalte and iam trying to get it work (but i can make minor changes it if needed). FYI, i could write some dummycode in a completely different folder and could get the standard_tags output properly. So, the remote state and the values exist, it's just a question of getting this issue fixed, which looks more of folder structure related.

Sure, but I don't see any reason to call it like module within the same directory. You could remove the module call and if everything else is configured properly, it should work.

I corrected a typo in the question. It is source = "../" (and not source = "./") The issue is still unresolved.

I'm now confused even more. Where is the module code you are calling located? In the state_initiatlization directory, or outside? With the source directive you are using, you are telling terraform to look outside of your current directory.

I had variable definition for 'standard_tags' in the root as well as child module. It worked after I commented out the one in child module. The module resource definition in our template is in the child module, so it is a bit confusing. Will change it to the std notation.
